# Integral of average potential over spherical surface due to single point charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, integration

I'm working through Introduction to Electrodynamics 4th Ed by Griffiths, and I'm really struggling to follow some of his integrations. Searching online for how to do these often proves fruitless as well, as I don't really know where to begin.

One that's given me trouble is this, used in a proof he makes under the section for Laplace's Equation (page 117):

$$ V_{ave} = \frac {1} {4 \pi R^2}\frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int [z^2 + R^2 - 2zR\cos(\theta)]^{-1/2}R^2\sin(\theta)\mathrm d\theta \mathrm d\phi $$

The solution he arrives at:
$\frac {1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac qz   $

What techniques would you apply to solve this integral? I feel like the only way to acclimate myself to these integrals is to observe the process, rather than stare at it. I would deeply appreciate seeing this worked out, but I understand if this is the wrong forum to ask this question, in which case I would ask where I should go to have this answered.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: Probably the case, I'll definitely redirect further questions along these same lines to Mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct substitution: $\xi=-\cos\theta, d\xi=\sin\theta\,d\theta$.

In
$$
\displaystyle\int \frac{\sin\theta\,d\theta}{\sqrt{z^2+R^2-2zR\cos\theta}}
$$
set $\xi=-\cos\theta,\,d\xi=\sin\theta\,d\theta$ to get
$$
\displaystyle \frac{d\xi}{\sqrt{z^2+R^2+2Rz\xi}}=\frac{1}{zR}\sqrt{z^2+R^2+2Rz\xi}\, ,
$$
so your original integral 
\begin{align}
\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin\theta\,d\theta}{\sqrt{z^2+R^2-2zR\cos\theta}}&=\frac{1}{zR}\sqrt{z^2+R^2-2zR\cos\theta}\ \Bigl\vert_0^{\pi}\, ,\\
&=\frac{1}{zR}\left(\sqrt{(z+R)^2}-\sqrt{(z-R)^2}\right)\, ,\\
&=\frac{1}{zR}\left(z+R-\vert z-R\vert\right)
\end{align}
It appears that your answers follows because $z>R$ so $\vert z-R\vert=z-R$ and thus $\frac{1}{zR}(z+R-z+R)=\frac{2}{z}$.  There is an extra $2\pi$ that comes from $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi$.

Comment: I'm honestly still confused as to how to work this out, although I see how this first step makes sense.

Comment: So at this point, I'm feeling pretty dense, but I think I'm almost there. Thanks for being patient with me. A couple questions:
1. When you say "so you original equation", I assume you've just substituted u back in, right? Why does the term outside the radical not have R in the denominator, when it does in your result when you integrate over u?
2. How do you perform the manipulation from line 1 to line 2 in "so your original equation" to split the terms of the radical?

Comment: @Bookie possible typo fixed.  Not sure how to understand your comment about going from line 1 to line 2... I just insert $\theta=\pi$ in expression, and subtract $\theta=0$.

Comment: Yeah for some reason I totally slipped on the fact that we were finishing the integration there. That + the typo being fixed has this making sense to me now. Thank you for your patience and help.

Comment: @Bookie no problem.